# Asp.net MVC integration test and websecurity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing an ASP.Net MVC 4 website and I would like to test it. In the controller that I would like to test, I call

> WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount

and I have some logic around this call that I would like to test. So I test the whole action (and in the future, I will have to do it more than once).

So this is my test

```
[TestMethod]
        public void RegisterUser()
        {
            // Arrange
            var controller = new UserController("TestConnection");

            // Act
            var user= new UserModel()
            {
                MailAddressTemp = "dummyuser@gmail.com",
                Password = "password",
                ConfirmPassword = "password",
                FirstName = "firstname",
                LastName = "lastname",
            };
            TestHelper.ValidateViewModel(user, controller);
            if (!controller.ModelState.IsValid)
                Assert.Inconclusive("Model should be valid!");
            controller.Register(user);
            using (var context = new PatientDbContext("TestConnection"))
            {
                var userProfile = context.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MailAddress == "dummyuser@gmail.com");
                Assert.IsNotNull(userProfile);
                Assert.AreEqual("dummyuser@gmail.com", WebSecurity.CurrentUserName);
                Assert.IsTrue(WebSecurity.UserExists("dummyuser@gmail.com"));
                WebSecurity.Logout();
                var islogged = WebSecurity.Login("dummyuser@gmail.com", "password");
                Assert.IsTrue(islogged);
            }
        }
```

My problem is that I have an exception when I want to use

> WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount

This is the exception

> To call this method, the "Membership.Provider" property must be an
>   instance of "ExtendedMembershipProvider"

I will need to use WebSecurity in my future tests. I'm from the WPF world and in my integration test, I was able to start an application container and test it from the unit test solution.
Here, it looks like the web application is not started when I run the tests and I don't know how to do it.

My questions:

> How can I use WebSecurity in my test solution and solve the exception?
>
> How can I start my application so that all objects are loaded like in
>   a live application and test my actions from the code in the unit
>   tests?

I don't want a browser. I want to be able to do something like

```
StartApp()
var result = MyController.Action(params)//My action uses WebSecurity for instance
Assert.IsTrue(something from result)
```

Any help will be helpful!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found part of the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753864/to-call-this-method-the-membership-provider-property-must-be-an-instance-of). I needed to add this in my app.config in my test solution

```
<system.web>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
```

Before my tests, I had to call

```
    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "MailAddress", autoCreateTables: true);
```

You must add WebMatrix.webData and WebMtrix.Data in reference in your test project and set "Copy local" to true

Answer (score 1):

You'd better to create decorator around static methods of WebSecurity class. You will be able to mock it and isolave your controller core. For example:

```
public interface IWebSecurity
{
    bool CreateUserAndAccount(....);
}

public class MyWebSecurity: IWebSecurity
{
    public bool CreateUserAndAccount(...)
    {
        WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(...);
    }
}
```

in your test code you will be able to do (using Moq test framework):

```
var webSecurity=new Mock<IWebSecurity>();
var controller = new UserController("TestConnection", webSecurity.Object);
```

Comment: That doesn't work because when I call WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount, I add data in my database based on this action and its result (foreign Key etc...)

Comment: The rest of your code remains the same, you just decorate call to WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount. Of course you can mock output of this function. So you will test controller code, not everything including membership provider code

Comment: Doesn't this go against the idea of an "integration" test. From the [wiki description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing): _"Test cases are constructed to test whether all the components within assemblages interact correctly, for example across procedure calls or process activations, and this is done after testing individual modules, i.e. unit testing."_.  So you would want to be executing expected components, rather than mocked ones.