# ASP.NET MVC4 in development machine, while Click on Log Off error occured

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, logoff

I developed asp.net MVC 4 site. I had implemented CustomMembership and CustomRole things.
I am getting error while I click on LogOff button 
error message:
**To call this method, the "Membership.Provider" property must be an instance of "ExtendedMembershipProvider".**

this is my Web.Config file.

```
<membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
    <add name="MyMembershipProvider" type="MvcApplicationTest.CustomMembershipProvider"
       connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" 
       enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
       enablePasswordReset="true"  
       requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
       requireUniqueEmail="false"
       maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
       minRequiredPasswordLenth ="6"
       minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
       passwordAttemptWindow ="10"
       applicationName ="MvcApplicationTest.Client.Web"
         />
  </providers>
</membership>

<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>

<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
    <add name="MyRoleProvider" type="MvcApplicationTest.Models.CustomRoleProvider"/>
  </providers>  
</roleManager>

<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Thank You,

Comment: Are you trying to implement ACL?

Comment: custommembership implementing, While I click on LOGOFF it shows error "To call this method, the "Membership.Provider" property must be an instance of "ExtendedMembershipProvider".

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753864/to-call-this-method-the-membership-provider-property-must-be-an-instance-of